# Insert bit into uint16_t

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

Is there any efficient algorithm that allows to insert bit `bit` to position `index` when working with `uint16_t`? I've tried reading bit-by-bit after `index`, storing all such bits into array of `char`, changing bit at `index`, increasing `index`, and then looping again, inserting bits from array, but could be there a better way? So I know how to get, set, unset or toggle specific bit, but I suppose there could be better algorithm than processing bit-by-bit.

```
uint16_t bit_insert(uint16_t word, int bit, int index);
bit_insert(0b0000111111111110, 1, 1); /* must return 0b0100011111111111 */
```

P.S. The solution must be in pure ANSI-compatible C. I know that `0b` prefix may be specific to `gcc`, but I've used it here to make things more obvious.

Comment: Why need a loop? Just shift all the adjacent bits at the same time. And what do you mean "insert" here and where do you count bits from? In your code you're inserting a 0 bit at index 0 but I see only new "1" bits in the result in both the left and right

Comment: mea culpa; here should have been 1 as second argument, not zero.

Answer (score 3):

Use bitwise operators:

```
#define BIT_INSERT(word, bit, index)  \
    (((word) & (~(1U << (index)))) | ((bit) << (index)))
```

Comment: he means "insert", that is shift the remaining bits to the left, not assign `bit` to the bit at `index`, and he's counting bits from MSB

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc his question is not clear as is not clear the provided example, so I took it as: compute a value with `bit` value at bit position `index` and the other bits set to those of `word`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Insert a bit `idx' positions from the right (lsb). */
uint16_t
bit_insert_lsb(uint16_t n, int bit, int idx)
{
    uint16_t lower;

    if (idx > 15) {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return 0U;
    }

    /* Get bits 0 to `idx' inclusive. */
    lower = n & ((1U << (idx + 1)) - 1);

    return ((n & ~lower) | ((!!bit) << idx) | (lower >> 1));
}

/* Insert a bit `idx' positions from the left (msb). */
uint16_t
bit_insert_msb(uint16_t n, int bit, int idx)
{
    uint16_t lower;

    if (idx > 15) {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return 0U;
    }

    /* Get bits 0 to `16 - idx' inclusive. */
    lower = n & ((1U << (15 - idx + 1)) - 1);

    return ((n & ~lower) | ((!!bit) << (15 - idx)) | (lower >> 1));
}
```

Bits are typically counted from the right, where the least significant bit (lsb) resides, to the left, where the most significant bit (msb) is located. I allowed for insertion from either side by creating two functions. The one expected, according to the question, is `bit_insert_msb`.

Both functions perform a sanity check, setting `errno` to `ERANGE` and returning 0 if the value of `idx` is too large. I also provided some of C99's `_Bool` behaviour for the `bit` parameter in the `return` statements: 0 is 0 and any other value is 1. If you use a C99 compiler, I'd recommend changing `bit`'s type to `_Bool`. You can then replace `(!!bit)` with `bit` directly.

I'd love to say it could be optimised, but that could very well make it less comprehensible.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you're counting bits from the left

```
mask = (1 << (16 - index + 1)) - 1;  // all 1s from bit "index" to LSB
// MSB of word (from left to index) | insert bit at index | LSB of word from (index-1)
word = (word & ~mask) | (bit << (16 - index)) | ((word & mask) >> 1);
```

There may be many ways more efficient but this way it's easy to understand

Comment: Try this with 0x8ffe instead of the example 0x0ffe. This doesn't work because when you use the ~ operator, you're accidentally turning on the sign bit in the mask, which will turn off the sign bit in the result.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune typing mistake, what I thought is "-1", not "~"